# Modman for third party extensions

Tags: extensions, modman

I know that I can have modman install my module to the application root, how do I have modman install and manage third party extensions?

For example,
I have a module name MyCompany_Mymodule. This is versioned with Git. In my IDE (eclipse), I have a project with just this module. I develop and test this module, then I commit to git. This module is linked (not cloned) by modman to the application root in my local development. The application root is some version of Magento that is NOT under version control. On the staging site, initially, I scp up everything in the base Magento install. As I develop my module, any commits to git are then uploaded to the staging site. There is NO git on the staging server.

Now, I'm suppose to install multiple third party extensions on the staging site. How do I do this with Modman? I know I can install with Magento Connect on the staging site, but I would like to have Modman do this for me. Is this a feature of Modman? Maybe I can list the repositories of third party extensions in the 'modman' file and when I do modman update on the staging site, it'll update the staging site for me?

Edit:
Here's what my project looks like:

```
my-project
    third-party
        Aoe_Scheduler
        magemonkey
    src
        app
        js
        skin
    modman
```

Here's my modman:

```
src/app/code/local                        app/code/local/
src/app/design/frontend/rwd/my-project    app/design/frontend/rwd/my-project/
src/app/etc/local.xml                     src/app/etc/
src/app/etc/modules/My_Project.xml        app/etc/modules/
src/skin/frontend/rwd/my-project          skin/frontend/rwd/my-project/                         
@shell rm -rf $PROJECT/var/cache/*

# Third party extensions
@import third-party/Aoe_Scheduler
@import third-party/magemonkey
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/razbakov/e6f69419f0ec1eb816ac

Answer (score 1):

You can obviously only install third party extensions that have their own modman file. If that is the case then you could do it similarly to how you have in your example. You can either clone, checkout, hgclone or link these extensions depending on their source, these will be put in the /path/to/magento/.modman directory. You could do this locally, then scp the .modman directory to the staging server and finally redeploy the extensions on the staging site.